# Classification of the integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Is this integral improper or not?
$$\int \limits_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\log(1 + a\cos x)}{\cos x}dx, a^2 < 1 ?$$
Is there any problem in $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: absolutely improper but it is removable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrand function is not defined at the midpoint of the integration range, but that is not a real issue since $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a removable discontinuity:
$$ \lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\log(1+a\cos x)}{\cos x}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\log(1+a\sin z)}{\sin z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{a\sin z}{\sin z} = a$$
The symmetry just invoked also implies that
$$ I(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\log(1+a\cos x)}{\cos x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\log(1+a\sin z)-\log(1-a\sin z)}{\sin z}\,dz $$

$$ I(a) = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\operatorname{arctanh}(a\sin z)\frac{dz}{\sin z}=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(au)}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du $$
where $I(0)=0$ and 
$$ I'(a)=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{(1-a^2 u^2)\sqrt{1-u^2}}=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1-a^2\sin^2\theta}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} $$
by setting $\theta=\arctan s$ and by applying partial fraction decomposition.
By integrating both sides with respect to $a$ we get:
$$\boxed{ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\log(1+a\cos x)}{\cos x}\,dx = \color{red}{\pi\arcsin(a)}}.$$
This can be proved by Fourier series and the properties of the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel), too.

Yet another approach is to realize that, due to Taylor series and Euler's Beta function,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(au)}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du&=&2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{a^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du\\&=&\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{a^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}\int_{0}^{1}v^n(1-v)^{-1/2}\,dv\\&=&\pi\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}a^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)\, 4^n}=\pi\int_{0}^{a}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually this integral is not well defined because the function is not for $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

But it can be fixed by defining the function at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

The integral doesn't depend on single points hence it doesn't matter how your function is defined in $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Nevertheless you still have to check if your integral exists… but because you don't have a pole in $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (consider that $$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\log(1 + a\cos x)}{\cos x} = \lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1+a\cos(x))}{a} = a$$ by l'Hopital's rule, so you can even extend it continuous in $\frac{\pi}{2}$) you just have to check if $$\lim_{t\to\pi} \int \limits_{0}^{t}\frac{\log(1 + a\cos x)}{\cos x}dx$$ exists…